# Linq to Entities exception

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Hi I have a query like this:

```
var queryGridData = from question in questions
   select new {
      i = question.Id,
      cell = new List<string>() { question.Id.ToString(), question.Note, question.Topic }
   };
```

The `ToString()` part needed to convert the `int` is causing:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String.ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Hmmmmmmmmmmm. I need it as a `string` to go into the `collection`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally perform *just enough* of the query in the database to provide the values you want, and do the rest in .NET:

```
var queryGridData = questions.Select(q => new { q.Id, q.Note, q.Topic })
                             .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest locally
                             .Select(q => new { i = q.Id,
                                                cell = new List<string> { 
                                                    q.Id.ToString(),
                                                    q.Note,
                                                    q.Topic
                                                } });
```

(This formatting is horrible, but hopefully it'll be easier to do nicely in an IDE where you've got more space :)